# Passing variable from one class instance to another using Python?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, variables, wxpython

I'm having trouble passing a variable defined in one class instance to another class instance. I am relatively new to using classes, but it is my understanding that variables can be passed from one instance to another by simply defining as part of the class instance (such as in the following example). While I've used this model in the past I've never attempted to do this using a GUI framework such as `wxPython`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

class Bar(object):
    def do_something(self, var):
        print var*3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(3)
    b = Bar()
    b.do_something(f.var)
```

The problem I'm having is that the wxPython instance seems to be predefined and will not accept any additional parameters (allowing me to only pass things like title, size, etc.) to the class instance.

The other issue I'm facing is I'm attempting to pass the variable three classes deep by calling a dialog window, and from the dialog I call a separate class designed to start a worker thread.

So my questions are:

1. **How can I pass the variable from the first class instance to the third class instance?**
2. **How can I override the wxPython instance to allow for the definition of additional variables?**
3. **OR, Could it be possible to create a custom event handler to pass the necessary data?**

To clarify...

I'm using Python and would like to think that I understand the fundamentals of programming using Classes and a GUI with frameworks such as Tkinter and wxPython (used in this project). I've written a main class/instance that gets some data from the user and I would like to be able to pass the information stored in self.main_instance_var and pass it along to a second class/instance (in this case a Progress Dialog window called from the first class.

When I attempted to use the above model in my Progress Dialog I got a very uninformative syntax error ('non-keyword arg after keyword arg'). Preventing me from further passing the variable from the Progress Dialog window on to the worker thread. If I had gotten an exception that would have been one thing but the syntax error I don't understand. Look below for a short example:

```
class ProgressDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, myVar):     # Generates syntax error on this line
        super(ProgressDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent, 
            title=title, size=(500, 110))
        self.var = myVar
```

Basic Source (by request, sorry its so dirty):

```
import time
import os, sys, wx
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher

########################################################################
class FtpValues(object):
    """ Returns a property attribute - called by FtpFileTransfer
    Used to set values/variables for Host, USERID, PASSWD, FILE """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        self.varList = None

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------    
    def GetValues(self):
        return self.varList

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def SetValues(self, HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE):
        self.varList = [HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE]

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def DelValues(self):
        del self.valList

    Values = property(GetValues, SetValues, DelValues, "Set/Get FtpValues")

    # http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

########################################################################
class FtpFileTransfer(Thread):
    """Test Worker Thread Class."""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.StartTransfer()        # start the thread

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def StartTransfer(self):        # was named run - started automatically                                    
        """Run Worker Thread."""    # when called by the start method
        # This is the code executing in the new thread.

        HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE = FtpValues.Values
        BLOCKSIZE = 57344
        try:
            ftp = FTP_TLS(HOST)
            ftp.login(USERID, PASSWD)
            ftp.prot_p()
            ftp.voidcmd("TYPE I")
            f = open(FILE, 'rb')
            datasock, esize = ftp.ntransfercmd(
                    'STOR %s' % os.path.basename(FILE))
            size = os.stat(FILE)[6]
            bytes_so_far = 0
            while 1:
                buf = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
                if not buf:
                    break
                datasock.sendall(buf)
                bytes_so_far += len(buf)
                msg = [bytes_so_far, size]
                Publisher().sendMessage("update", msg)
        except: raise
        finally:
            try:
                datasock.close()
                f.close()
                ftp.voidresp()
                ftp.quit()
                print 'Complete...'
            except: pass

        wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, "update", "Database Transfer Complete!")


########################################################################
class ProgressDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(ProgressDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent, 
            title=title, size=(500, 110))

        self.displayLbl = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Verifying Database Files... ', (20, 20)) #Preparing for Transfer...
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, -1, 100, (20, 45), (370, 24))        
        self.btn = btn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Cancel', (400, 45), (-1, 25))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        # listens for response from worker thread
        Publisher().subscribe(self.updateDisplay, "update")

        FtpFileTransfer()#.StartTransfer(HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE)        #Start the FTP Worker Thread
        #self.OnStart()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        FtpFileTransfer(HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnClose(self, event):
        """ Place Holder """
        if self.btn.GetLabel() == 'Finish':
            # Do Something!
            pass
        return None

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateDisplay(self, msg):
        """ Receives data from thread and updates the display """
        if isinstance(msg.data, list):
            bytes_so_far, size = msg.data
            k = 100 * bytes_so_far / size
            self.displayLbl.SetLabel("Sent %d of %d bytes %.1f%%" % (bytes_so_far, size, 100 * bytes_so_far / size))
            self.gauge.SetValue(k)
        else:
            self.displayLbl.SetLabel("%s" % msg.data)
            #self.btn.Enable()
            self.btn.SetLabel('Finish')


########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.displayLbl = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Amount of time since thread started goes here")
        self.btn = btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Start Thread")
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(panel, -1, 100, size=(370, 24))

        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.displayLbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.gauge, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.VarData()
        # create a pubsub receiver
        Publisher().subscribe(self.updateDisplay, "update")

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        """
        Runs the thread
        """

        chgdep = ProgressDialog(None, title='File Transfer. . .')
        chgdep.ShowModal()
        #chgdep.Destroy()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateDisplay(self, msg):
        """
        Receives data from thread and updates the display
        """
        if isinstance(msg.data, list):
            bytes_so_far, size = msg.data
            k = 100 * bytes_so_far / size
            self.displayLbl.SetLabel("Sent %d of %d bytes %.1f%%" % (bytes_so_far, size, 100 * bytes_so_far / size))
            self.gauge.SetValue(k)
        else:
            self.displayLbl.SetLabel("%s" % msg.data)
            self.btn.Enable()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def VarData(self):
        HOST = '127.0.0.1'
        USERID = 'test'
        PASSWD = 'P@ssw0rd'
        FILE = r'F:\Programming\temp\Test.zip'
        varList = [HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE]
        FtpValues.Values = HOST, USERID, PASSWD, FILE

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The issues that you're having with inheritance and ProgressDialog seem different to me than questions about passing variables between classes; and I suspect that answering the ProgressDialog question will address the main issue.  Could you give a minimal but runnable program where ProgressDialog doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like using wx.lib.pubsub to pass information between classes. I do it all the time in my applications. You can read about it here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

If you need to post data from a thread, you will need to use a thread-safe method like wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent. You can combine these with pubsub by calling your pubsub publisher inside one of the thread-safe methods. I show how to do just that here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

There's also a good article on threads and wxPython on their wiki: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: I'm still new to this but I'm not sure that would work in this case... I'm currently using this method to pass updates from the worker thread back to the ProgressDialog window but I'm not sure how this would work when trying to pass a variable forward from the main application instance on to the worker thread; could you show me an example of this?

Comment: I wonder if this might be possible using some type of custom event...?

Comment: I added some more suggestions to my answer, but yes, you could use a custom event with wx.PostEvent, I think.

Comment: Lets see if I understand... lets say I start instance#3 in a separate worker thread, instance#3 completes some long running process and passes data back to instance#2 via the pubsub event-handler. Instance#2 gets the data (msg) from pubsub and does-something. Now what if the roles are reversed? lets say, instance#1 gets some data from the user and starts instance#2, from there we start instance#3 (worker thread) and do-something... but before instance#3 can start it must retrieve the data from instance#1. Here is the problem I foresee (maybe I'm over thinking this?) Continued...

Comment: Since pubsub appears to be event driven, in that it requires a msg be sent/updated for the receiver to capture the data... would it not fail since nothing has changed since instance#1 was started??? Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Pubsub only fires when you tell it to programmatically. The user cannot fire it. You wouldn't start a new thread until you could pass it some data, right? If you need thread concurrency, you'll probably want to ask on the wxPython mailing list as I don't have much experience in that.

Answer (score 1):

The approaches suggested in the question are the preferred way of doing things in Python.  Statements like `b.do_something(f.var)` and `__init__(self, parent, title, myVar)` are **perfectly good** ways to pass information between classes.

It's common when starting out, but my guess here is that you've taken a small syntax error somewhere and are thinking it's implying that you're taking the wrong general approach.  Instead, your general approach looks fine, but you just need to figure out what's causing the specific error.

Comments on other answers:

1) Set/get functions work well too, but Python prefers the [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) approach.  (Personally, I still use set/get methods out of habit, but it's not as Pythonic.)

2) pubsub is great, but it's not a general tool for "passing information between classes", *e.g.*, one wouldn't want to use pubsub for i = int("2").  Pubsub is more for cases where one has, for example, two wxFrames that need to communicate a bit of information.  There's a reason it's a part of wxPython and not Python.

Comment: You're right. However, the OP seemed to be talking about when passing data from a dialog or a frame back to another frame is different. The original frame is already instantiated and can't accept new arguments. And you can download PubSub for any Python project too

Comment: Defining properties makes a lot of sense... only this results in the Dialog window delaying/freezing until the worker thread has completed. Do I have to implement asynchronous programming to get this to work? [This is starting to get really complicated!!!]

Comment: At this point, I think this is all too confused and unclear.  The initial question was about passing variables between classes (which I think was answered), but now it seems to be more about threads (which is unclear).  My suggestion is to take each concept and write the **smallest program possible** which tests it, and then add the ideas to the final program one at a time.

Comment: Two points: 1) why are you using a wxDialog with a thread? The point of a dialog is to stop program flow.  2) Remove the ftp stuff from this while you're figuring it out and replace with time.sleep, or whatever.

Comment: point1: I'm new to GUI's and the wxDialog seemed logical... is there a better, more pythonic way? point2: I'll work on it and create a new post to address the issues I seem to be having implementing threads.

Comment: In all GUIs I know, dialogs are just special types of frames, generally for getting user input, with preset buttons (OK, Cancel, Yes, No, etc), and are usually used in modal mode (where they block program flow).  Since you don't want any of this (as far as I know), a simple frame will do, but if you want an OK button you could use a "modeless" dialog (use Show instead of ShowModel), see http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxdialog.html for example.  (But here I'm guessing at what you want... as I said, I think this question has become un-precise and with too many things tangled in it.)

Answer (score 0):

In OOP if you want to pass data into and out of an object you should define a set/get function in that class so that you can get data from that object as well as set data in that object.  So in your case each instance of your object would call the respective get/set function to pass the data back and forth between your objects.

Comment: Thank you for the insight into Object Oriented Programming. However, I was hoping for a slightly more detailed response. I suppose it was my fault though... not specifying which programming language I'm using or  including some or all of the code I've written. For future reference, I'm using Python v2.7 and I'll work on updating my post to include more detail (including source). Thanks again for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

You may have worked through this months ago, but I just ran into the very same issue with a wxPython dialog, and got it to work by using informing a global within the function:

```
elusive_variable="" # declare outside class & function

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def onOpenFile(self, event):
        global elusive_variable
        # ...other stuff here
        elusive_variable="Oh hi Mark"

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyForm()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
print elusive_variable # variable is liberated!!!
```

There might be some more enlightned way but this works...

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example:

```
class One:
    param1 = ['a', 'b']

class Two:
    i = One()
    print i.param1
```

Save the above code in .py file and run it . You should see the output
I guess this can be a simple way to exchange variables from one class to another